# Avoid Pasting excel data into a DataGridView header

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I need to paste excel data to my data grid for which i found the below code , however the header of my data grid view is being populated with the first row of the pasted data(as per the below screenshot).
I searched for the similar problems here but none of them are solving this .Kindly help me how to solve this.
the copied data should not be pasted for column headers , the paste range should only be restricted to two columns.

[image: Original form]

[image: After Pasting]

code:

```
private void Btnlotpaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            if (dataGridView2.RowCount > 0)
                dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();

            if (dataGridView2.ColumnCount > 0)
                dataGridView2.Columns.Clear();

            bool columnsAdded = false;
            string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
            int j = 0;
            foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
            {
                string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

                if (!columnsAdded)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                        dataGridView2.Columns.Add("col" + i, pastedRowCells[i]);

                    columnsAdded = true;
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }

                dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                int myRowIndex = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1;

                using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = dataGridView2.Rows[j])
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                        myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

after removing `dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();`
[image: after]

Comment: remove the `dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
`? Maybe you clear the title, or you could try to add a row before you paste your data.

Comment: Hi @高鵬翔   hank you for your response ..now two columns extra added for the first row.(picture added in question)

Comment: Is `dataGridView2.Columns.Add("col" + i, pastedRowCells[i]);` the data or the title?

Comment: tiltle it seems , i found the code online

Comment: Try to  `using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = dataGridView2.Rows[j])` using `dataGridView2.Rows[j+1]` to try.

Comment: now this error is coming while pasting `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'`

Comment: Oh! I miss the `continue;` You should add `j++` before your `continue` and turn `j+1` back to `j`, because you miss a `j++` when the first loop continue, it didn't add in the first time when `j=0`

Comment: Hi  @高鵬翔  Same error , i have updated the code as per your instruction and pasted the same in above question , can you please check once.

Comment: Maybe try to remove whole `if (!columnsAdded)` region to run? if it work or disappear the title..

Comment: now the error is `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.'`

Comment: remove the `dataGridView2.Columns.Clear();` ,too.

Comment: thank you now it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it may be like this:

```
private void Btnlotpaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        
        bool columnsAdded = false;
        string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
        int j = 0;
        foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
        {
            string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

          
            dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
            int myRowIndex = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1;

            using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = dataGridView2.Rows[j])
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                    myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```